# RecordSet with row number to Object[][]?

Tags: java, sql, parsing, object, recordset

For example I got a table on my database like the following:

```
| id | first_name | last_name   |
+----+------------+-------------+
| 23 | Hans       | Mueller     |
| 42 | John       | Kramer      |
| 23 | Max        | Mustermann  |
```

How can I get my recordset into an `Object[][]`, but starting with a column of the actual row number (e.g. below)?

```
{
    {1, 23, "Hans", "Mueller"},
    {2, 42, "John", "Kramer"},
    {3, 76, "Max", "Mustermann"}
};
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get my recordset into an Object[][], but starting with a column of the actual row number

If you are looking for out-of-the-box JDBC API, I doubt if there is one. If you are willing to use `ResultSetMetaData`, then you can write a function to form the same as follows:

1. take a `ResultSet`
2. get the `ResultSetMetaData` using `rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData()`
3. get the column count using `rsmd.getColumnCount()`
4. iterate through each row in the result set and get the column value using the column index, starting from 1 (unlike arrays whose index starts from 0).
5. get the data type of the column using `rsmd.getColumnType(columnIndex)` and add the appropriate instance based on the type (can do a switch on java.sql.Types appropriately).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). If this thingie as to far from your actual knowledge try to create your own class Person like:

```
public class Person {
  int id;
  String firstname;
  String surname;

  public void initByResultSet(ResultSet result) {
    [...]
  }
}
```

Or if you really want to have this `Object[][]` create a view in the database which gives u the rownumber.